# Fast dfs implementation with python

Tags: python, performance, graph, distance, depth-first-search

I am working on a problem with Python and i want to make my algorithm faster.
To save your precious time i will not tell you in details about the problem, but the point is i have to do a dfs to find the connected components size in an unoriented graph.

I can make the unoriented graph in the way that i want : matrix, dictionnary with list as items, dictionnary with sets as items ....

Right now i have a working dfs and it is fast (300000 nodes about 5 secs to finish finding all connected components). I used a dictionnary with lists as items to represent the graph :

```
graph = {  1 : [2],
           2 : [1, 3],
           3 : [2],
           4 : [] }
```

I thought maybe if i use a numpy matrix for the graph it will make my algorithm faster but i am afraid this will impose a O(n^2) complexity ...

What do you think ? Is there maybe a better and faster way to implement dfs and represent a graph ???

EDIT:
Here i have the code of the dfs that i used (i did not write the code for it) I added some modification to be able to compute all of the connected component. I added a set called "visited" and every time i visit a point i add it to "visited".
Than i do a dfs for every point that is not in visited.

```
def dfs(G,s) : 
    P,Q={s :None},[s]   
        while Q :       
            u=Q[-1]         
            R=[y for y in G[u] if y not in P]   
            if R :      
                v=random.choice(R)  
                P[v]=u          
                Q.append(v)         
            else :          
                Q.pop()     
return P
```

Bonus question : In my algorithm i calculate distances, i mean a lot a lot of euclidean distances. What do you think is the fastest way to calculate a distance in Python ?? ( i tried nympy.norm, cdist, pdist and none is fast enough ... sad but True)

Comment: can you please share your complete code ?

Comment: i added the code :)

Comment: Tried `math.hypot()` yet?

Comment: nope what does it do ?

Comment: i read about it. How can i use it to calculate distance if i do nkt have a right triangle ? And have you tested it speed ?

Comment: The triangle is formed by two sides parallel to the coordinate system's axis and one side (the hypothenuse) being the the vector from one point to the next. And no, I haven't tested its speed. It was just the simplest solution to calculate the distance and it was missing from your list.

Comment: Omg i tested it is fast. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

For graph theoretic questions, you probably should consult the excellent python package [networkx](https://networkx.org). They have also implemented various graph traversal algorithms (see [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/traversal.html) for a list)

Comment: I will go check it :)